# ActiveMQ : KahaDB and LevelDB slow disk space expansion

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-karaf, leveldb, apache-servicemix, kahadb

**Has anyone observed a creeping disk space growth of their ActiveMQ KahaDB or LevelDB stores ?**

We are using the following :

- Windows Server 2008 SP1 (for deployment) and Windows 7 SP1 (for development)
- Java 1.7
- ActiveMQ 5.11.1 and 5.13.2 (tried both KahaDB and LevelDB)
- ServiceMix 5.4.0, with its Karaf server hosting Camel-based Java application beans and its ActiveMQ server unused
- Message rates = 200 XML messages per second coming in and about the same going out (translated into JSON by the Java application beans)
- Number of queues = about 50 queues across which are shared the above messages; 2 queues in particular are handling up to half the traffic
- All messages set to:

  - delivery persistence = false
  - time to live (TTL) = either 1 or 2 minutes (maximum)

**KahaDB**

When using ActiveMQ with a KahaDB, I have watched the db*.log files initially "leap-frog" from db-1.log to db-2.log then to db-3.log and so on, with the older db*.log files being cleaned up (deleted) as expected. Then at some point may be 10 hours later, the older db*.log files stop getting cleaned up; new db*.log files appear and the KahaDB begins to expand at about 4 GB per day. And when it eventually reaches our configured 50 GB cap, the server of course stops working.

It seems as if a small minority messages are failing to expire (in spite of being given a TTL) and thus block normal clean up. I've tried to manually delete the old db*.log files but I am blocked from doing so with a warning that those files are still in use.

The KahaDB db*.log files are "semi-readable" (!) in a text editor; i.e. I can recognise application messages but this does not tell me much about what has really happened.

**LevelDB**

I've recently tried using LevelDB with ActiveMQ 5.13.2, and the store still appears to expand albeit much more slowly (about 200 MB per day).

I believe the LevelDB data store uses compression; most files appear to be binary and thus quite opaque without a suitable reader/browser.

Has anyone found or implemented a tool to read/browse the non-persistent messages of a KahaDB or LevelDB message store ?

**Our Configuration**

Below is what our **activemq.xml** typically looks like :

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
        lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
        init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>

    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="XXXX" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
                <policyEntries>
                    <policyEntry topic=">" >
                        <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                            <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                        </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    </policyEntry>
                    <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
                        <deadLetterStrategy>
                            <discarding /> 
                        </deadLetterStrategy>
                    </policyEntry>
                </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>

        <!--
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="true" connectorPort="1099"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!--
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>
        -->
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <levelDB directory="${activemq.data}/leveldb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>

        <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <networkConnectors>
            <networkConnector
                    uri="XXX"
                    networkTTL="XXX"
                    duplex="XXX"
                    prefetchSize="XXX"
                    userName="${networkconnector.username}"
                    password="${networkconnector.password}"
                    name="XXX" >
                <excludedDestinations>
                </excludedDestinations>
                <staticallyIncludedDestinations>
                    <queue physicalName="XXX" /> 
                    <queue physicalName="XXX" />
                </staticallyIncludedDestinations>
            </networkConnector>
        </networkConnectors>

        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="amqp"              uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:XXXX?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="openwire"          uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:XXXX?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="openwire-outbound" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:XXXX?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>
        <plugins>
            <simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
                <users>
                    <authenticationUser username="XXX"   password="XXX"   groups="XXX" />
                </users>
            </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
            <authorizationPlugin>
                <map>
                    <authorizationMap>
                        <authorizationEntries>
                            <authorizationEntry topic=">"                    read="XXX"  write="XXX"  admin="XXX" />
                            <authorizationEntry queue=">"                    read="XXX"  write="XXX"  admin="XXX" />
                            <authorizationEntry queue="XXX"                  read="XXX"  write="XXX"  admin="XXX" />
                            <authorizationEntry queue="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>"  read="XXX"  write="XXX"  admin="XXX" />
                            <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>"  read="XXX"  write="XXX"  admin="XXX" />
                        </authorizationEntries>
                        <tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry>
                            <tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry read="tempDestinationAdmins" write="tempDestinationAdmins" admin="tempDestinationAdmins" />
                        </tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry>
                    </authorizationMap>
                </map>
            </authorizationPlugin>
            <runtimeConfigurationPlugin checkPeriod="1000" />
        </plugins>
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>
    </broker>
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Not really much of a question here.

Comment: OK, to finish the question at the top : "Has anyone observed a creeping disk space growth of their ActiveMQ KahaDB or LevelDB stores, and if so what did they do to remedy the problem ?"

Comment: There are literally dozens of things that can cause that-- most usually caused by the clients. A number of leading causes are messages in .DLQ's that are not being cleared out, mis-behaving consumers, transactions not completing, slow consumers, etc.